# Are the Zombies in Zombieland actually undead?

Tags: horror, zombieland

In the movie adaptation of *Zombieland*, are the Zombies specifically reanimated corpses\undead in the same way as Zombies in Franchise such as The Walking Dead?

For example, can they starve to death, or will their heads live on if cut off?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyAkwqhdB9Y - It became increasingly harder for the makers to ground the films in reality.

Answer (score 15):

They're still alive, according to the film's makers, just [infected](https://zombieland.fandom.com/wiki/Mad_Zombie_Disease).

> *Ruben Fleischer, special effects makeup designer Tony Gardner, and
> Tony Gardner's team researched infectious diseases, and their physical
> manifestations in the extreme stages. Explains SFX makeup artist
> Stephen Prouty, "What we wanted to show was that these people were
> infected. T**hey're still alive, but they're ravaged with fever so
> they're always wet and dripping,** they're hemorrhaging from all their
> orifices and spewing up a black bile-like substance."*
>
> <sub><sup>[Female.com.au - Zombieland Interview](https://www.female.com.au/zombieland.htm)</sup></sub>

and

> **Q: How much did you focus on the rules of zombies-- fast vs. slow, how to kill them, etc.?**
>
> **RF:** *I think we were pretty clear. We definitely went with the fast zombies, the viral zombies, like from 28 Days Later. **Our zombies you don't have to kill by shooting in the head. They're not undead. They don't come back from the grave. They're people that have become infected as opposed to people who have died and supernaturally risen from the grave. Zombie purists don't even call our zombies zombies, because to be a zombie you have to be undead.** That's something zombie purists can fight about for years and years to come.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Exclusive Interview: Zombieland Director Ruben Fleischer](https://www.cinemablend.com/new/Exclusive-Interview-Zombieland-Director-Ruben-Fleischer-14969.html)</sup></sub>

It follows that anything that would kill a normal (uninfected) human would kill an infected 'zombie' human.

Comment: _the viral zombies, like from 28 Days Later_ Oh no, they forgot that it's not zombies in that movie.

Comment: It looked like the zombies in the Zombieland movie survived for 10 entire years without eating between the first and the second movie though.

Comment: @Clockwork Re your first comment - isn't that the entire point of the last two sentences? It's just as easy to ignore/argue with the makers of 28 Days Later saying "they're not zombies" as it is to ignore the makers of this movie saying "they are zombies".

Comment: @Clockwork - Discussed in the video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wyAkwqhdB9Y). The ones that survived are unusually hardy.

Comment: I believe this is what George A. Romero came up with - not undead, just infected.